# Statement on an abelian group being isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-sum, direct-product

Let $A$ be an abelian group such that $A$$\otimes$$\Bbb R$ $= 0$. Then $A$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Is this statement true or fase? How can I show this with a short justification or a counterexample?

Please help me..

Comment: I think $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ should be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $ A = \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$, then $A \otimes \mathbb{R} = 0$, because we have $\frac{p}{q} \otimes x = \frac{p}{q} \otimes \frac{q x}{q} = p \otimes \frac{x}{q} = 0$.
However, $A$ is not isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups. ([See here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139039/show-that-mathbbq-mathbbz-cannot-be-decomposed-into-the-direct-sum-o))

The statement is however true for finitely generated abelian groups, in this case it follows from the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: We need $A$ not isomorphic to a direct SUM of cyclic groups. Not direct product

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, but in the thread I linked, it is shown that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not a direct sum of cyclic groups.